# ODBC ExecuteNonQuery() hangs

Tags: c#, .net, mariadb, odbc

I've got an interesting problem. I have a data connector from which I execute INSERT and UPDATE commands to the database. The problem is that sometimes everything runs okey and my query gets inserted, but sometimes ExecuteNonQuery method just freezes and my dataconnector just stops and it doesn't throw any exception neither does it throw any timeout. There is a code snippet:

```
    OdbcCommand insertCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();

    insertCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO `table` 
                    (name, creation, modified, modified_by)
                    VALUES (
                    ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", operation.ExternalProductionOrderLineOperationId);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@produced_qty", Convert.ToDecimal(operation.Quantity));
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_operation_type", productionOrder.ProductOperationType);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_articulus", productionOrder.ProductArticulus);

    _logger.LogInformation("Operacija paruosta exportinimui!"); <----------- THIS IS THE PLACE, sometimes it runs okey, sometimes it freezes

    try
    {
        var n = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (n != 0)
        {
            await UpdateProductionOrderLineOperation(productionOrder, operation, true);
            _logger.LogInformation("operation nr: {x} exported", counter);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("operation nr: {x} failed to export");
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("InvalidOperationException: {x}", e.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Exception: {x}", e.ToString());
    }
}
catch (OdbcException e)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("OdbcException: {x}", e.ToString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Exception: {x}", e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your question says “sometimes ExecuteNonQuery method just freezes” but your code says “sometimes it freezes” at `_logger.LogInformation`. Which is it?

Comment: It always executes _logger.LogInformation and freezes on the insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @PovilasDirse did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, managed to make it work

Answer (score 0):

put this line of code in using block..maybe it resolves the issue

var n = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Put the try block above the OdbcCommand instead, or better yet where you're opening the connection.  Because the error you're experiencing is happening before any exception handling, that's why the app craps out.

Comment: Yes, I have try catch block on that too